# Buscar linhas das ultimas 24h que mais se repetem(MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, query

```
'SELECT `from`, `to`, count(*) AS num_clicks
FROM my_rank
WHERE my_rank_data
BETWEEN "'.$yesterday.'" AND "'.$today.'"
ORDER BY num_clicks DESC LIMIT 0,20';
```

Acima estou tentando pegar os campos "from" e "to" de uma tabela, porém só quero as linhas das ultimas 24h, e preciso que me retorne somente as 20 linhas que mais se repetem dessas 24h. Porém o resultado acima me devolve as linhas que não são as que mais se repetem no intervalo das datas dadas.

Comment: As linhas que mais se repetem são as que têm maior `num_clicks`?

Comment: Não tenho certeza, acho que isso fiz errado esse "count(*) AS num_clicks". Minha intenção era que fosse esse "num_clicks", e sendo, o que faço com ele? terei só o numero de quantas vezes se repete, eu preciso da linha que mais se repete. Usaria um ORDER BY num_clicks DESC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer algo assim:

```
SELECT `from`, `to`, COUNT(*) AS num_clicks
FROM my_rank
WHERE my_rank_data >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY `from`, `to`
ORDER BY num_clicks DESC
```

Para usar uma função agregada, como COUNT(), você precisa indicar como quer agrupar os registros (nesse caso, para fazer essa contagem), e isso você faz com o GROUP BY. Assim ele vai agrupar os registros que contenham o mesmo valor nos campos **from** e **to** e gerar um campo com a contagem dessa repetição de registros.

Ao organizar pelo contador **num_clicks**, de forma decrescente, você terá primeiro os registros que mais se repetem.

Eu consultei esse post aqui:

> [Find records with a date field in the last 24 hours [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8079745/8133067)

e esse aqui:

> [Find most frequent value in SQL column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12235631/8133067)

para escrever esta resposta.

Comment: Só faltou o "LIMIT 20;"

Comment: Eu me compliquei aqui, na verdade esse "from" e "to" é a chave primeira de outra tabela, tem como eu selecionar os valores desta outra tabela a partir do "from" e "to" que recuperar e lista os 20 com o valor do campo nome da outra tabela?

Comment: Eu não coloquei o LIMIT 20 porque quando li sua pergunta a primeira vez ainda não tinha esse detalhe especificado!
Então, depende. Você poderia resgatar campos dessa outra tabela ligando as duas tabelas através de um JOIN, mas, para colocar mais campos sendo retornados pelo SELECT, esses campos teriam que estar na cláusula GROUP BY também, porque, lembre-se que os campos retornados por esse SELECT vieram de várias linhas, então, só dá para trazer esses campos se eles forem todos iguais nas linhas que estão sendo agrupadas.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/278016/buscar-campo-de-tabela-com-resultado-de-query-de-uma-tabela-diferente?noredirect=1&lq=1 criei uma pergunta nova para essa questão.

Comment: Por exemplo, se a primeira linha retornada trouxe _num_clicks=5_, quer dizer que haviam 5 linhas na tabela que tinham o mesmo valor em ambos os campos, _from_ e _to_. Se você adicionar um terceiro campo para ser retornado, ele também tem que ter o mesmo valor nessas 5 linhas, caso contrário, não daria para retornar o valor desse terceiro campo nessa primeira linha. Não sei se ficou claro.

Comment: Acho que então não daria, vou ter que resolver no PHP e puxar por outra query, porque no caso o from e to são diferentes e iriam retornar linhas diferentes da outra tabela, então ao todo seriam 40 linhas não 20, seria difícil separá-las, é melhor criar outra query mesmo.

Comment: Eu dei uma olhada na outra pergunta, mas não sei se entendi muito bem. Em _other_table_ os campos _from_ e _to_ serão chave primária, o que significa que só haverá uma linha para a combinação dos dois?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/278016/buscar-campo-de-tabela-com-resultado-de-query-de-uma-tabela-diferente confere novamente, eu editei, está o código que já consegui o que quero, mas queria fazer isso apenas com a query.

Answer (score 1):

Da para fazer sim, ficaria dessa forma:

```
SELECT `from`, `to`, COUNT(*) AS num_clicks
FROM my_rank
WHERE my_rank_data >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
GROUP BY `from`, `to`
ORDER BY num_clicks DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: Opa, acabei de atualizar a pergunta. Era este `GROUP BY from, to` que deve estar faltando então.  Teria como explicar um pouco sobre ele?

Comment: Atualizei a resposta. Você tentou rodar essa `query`?

Comment: Eu não tenho sua base de teste para verificar se realmente esta funcionando, mas é nesse sentido que poderá resolver seu problema.

Comment: Sim, agora parece funcionar. Uma outra dúvida, minha data no campo do banco está assim "2017-06-29 12:41:58", tem algum problema? pois as variáveis $yesterday e $today estão apenas assim "2017-06-29".

Comment: No banco esta no formato correto, lembre que a função `NOW()` no `MySQL` retorna a hora atual. Como você quer sempre o ranking das ultimas 24 horas, acredito que não seja necessário utilizar uma variável que vem do `PHP`.

Comment: Mas se mesmo assim você quiser comparar a data do banco com a data que você tem no `PHP`, terá que converter. Por exemplo, `"SELECT * FROM my_rank WHERE DATE(my_rank_data) = '$today'";`.