# Buscar campo de tabela com resultado de query de uma tabela diferente?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, query

Fiz uma pergunta recentemente:

[Buscar linhas das ultimas 24h que mais se repetem(MySQL)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/277999/buscar-linhas-das-ultimas-24h-que-mais-se-repetemmysql)

E foi respondida, agora estou com uma outra dúvida. Faço o seguinte para buscar `from` e `to` das linhas mais repetidas das ultimas 24h, porém há um problema, `from` e `to` não é o dado que precisava, está como o id de outra tabela, e precisa então do campo "nome" de outra tabela.

```
SELECT nome, idade 
FROM other_table 
WHERE myid = `from`, myid = `to`(SELECT `from`, `to`, COUNT(*) AS num_clicks
FROM my_rank
WHERE my_rank_data >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY `from`, `to`
ORDER BY num_clicks DESC LIMIT 20);
```

Estou tentando erroneamente como pode ver acima. Mas já consigo o resultado que quero com o código PHP abaixo, minha dúvida é se é possível conseguir o mesmo resultado apenas com a query.

```
$resultQueryClicks = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT `from`, `to`, COUNT(*) AS num_clicks
                                        FROM moeda_rank
                                        WHERE data_clique >= NOW() - INTERVAL 365 DAY
                                        GROUP BY `from`, `to`
                                        ORDER BY num_clicks DESC LIMIT 20');
        $rankMoeda =  array();
        while($aux = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultQueryClicks)) {
            $nameFrom = mysqli_query($con,'SELECT xml FROM moeda WHERE moeda = '.$aux["from"]);
            $nameTo = mysqli_query($con,'SELECT xml FROM moeda WHERE moeda = '.$aux["to"]);
            $auxFrom = mysqli_fetch_assoc($nameFrom);
            $auxTo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($nameTo);

            $rankMoeda[] = array(
                "from" => $auxFrom["xml"],
                "to" => $auxTo["xml"]
            );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia fazer algo assim, para retornar todos os campos que deseja em uma única consulta:

```
SELECT `r.from`, `r.to`, COUNT(r.*) AS num_clicks
     , mf.xml AS xmlFrom, mt.xml AS xmlTo
FROM moeda_rank AS r
INNER JOIN moeda AS mf ON mf.moeda = `r.from`
INNER JOIN moeda AS mt ON mt.moeda = `r.to`
WHERE r.data_clique >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY `r.from`, `r.to`, mf.xml, mt.xml
ORDER BY num_clicks DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

Mas não sei se teria algum impacto negativo de performance pelo fato de você ter que agrupar também os campos **xml** da tabela **moeda** (o conteúdo desse campo é de fato um arquivo XML?). De repente do jeito que você fez poderia ser melhor mesmo, mas faça alguns testes de performance e veja o que acha.

Não sei se você já sabe o conceito de JOINs, mas, o que eles fazem é combinar as linhas de duas tabelas, ou mais, através da ligação de um, ou mais, campos específicos.

Nesse caso, estamos pegando linhas da tabela **moeda_rank** mas estamos pedindo para a consulta combinar essas linhas como as linhas da tabela **moeda**, e estamos ligando as duas tabelas através do campo **moeda_rank.from** e do campo **moeda.moeda**.

Como também queremos pegar as linhas da tabela **moeda** que se ligam com o campo **moeda_rank.to**, fazemos um segundo JOIN.

Só que, como os campos **xmlFrom** e **xmlTo** foram acrescentados à lista de campos retornados pela cláusula SELECT, eles também devem ser acrescentados à cláusula GROUP BY.